SQL Developer LDAP Error code 50.The request control with Object identifier (OID) -Insufficient Access Rights
I am getting this error while creating an SQL developer connection via LDAP. I have access to LDAP file which is stored in under C:\Oracle19c_64\client\product\19.0.0\client_1\network\admin.while clicking load(as highlighted yellow) in Pic  I am getting this error. Could someone please help?

